# Unboxing a function

Tags: performance, haskell

I have a function that I am trying to optimize. This is part of a bigger code where I suspect this function is preventing `GHC` from unboxing `Int` arguments at higher level function that calls it. So, I wrote a simple test with two things in mind - understand the core, and try different things to see what makes GHC unbox it, so that I can apply the lessons to bigger code. Here is the function `cmp` with a `test` function wrapper:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Cmp
( cmp,
  test )
where
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U hiding (mapM_)
import Data.Word

cmp :: (U.Unbox a, Eq a) => U.Vector a -> U.Vector a -> Int -> Int -> Int
cmp a b !i !j = go a b 0 i j
               where
                 go v1 v2 !len !i !j| (i<n) && (j<m) && ((unsafeIndex v1 i) == (unsafeIndex v2 j)) = go v1 v2 (len+1) (i+1) (j+1)
                                    | otherwise = len
                   where
                    n = U.length a
                    m = U.length b
{-# INLINABLE cmp #-}

test ::  (U.Unbox a, Eq a) => U.Vector a -> U.Vector a -> U.Vector Int -> Int
test a b i = U.sum $ U.map (\x -> cmp a b x x) i
```

Ideally, `test` should call unboxed version of `cmp` with following signature (of course, correct me if I am wrong):

```
U.Vector a -> U.Vector a -> Int# -> Int# -> Int#
```

Looking at the core generated in `ghc 7.6.1` (command line option:`ghc -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-uniques -dsuppress-idinfo -dsuppress-module-prefixes -O2 -fllvm`), I see this for inner loop for `test` - snippets from core below, with my comments added:

```
-- cmp function doesn't have any helper functions with unboxed Int
--
cmp
  :: forall a.
     (Unbox a, Eq a) =>
     Vector a -> Vector a -> Int -> Int -> Int
...

-- This is the function that is called by test - it does keep the result
-- unboxed, but calls boxed cmp, and unboxes the result of cmp (I# y)
--
$wa
  :: forall a.
     (Unbox a, Eq a) =>
     Vector a -> Vector a -> Vector Int -> Int#
$wa =
  \ (@ a)
    (w :: Unbox a)
    (w1 :: Eq a)
    (w2 :: Vector a)
    (w3 :: Vector a)
    (w4 :: Vector Int) ->
    case w4
         `cast` (<TFCo:R:VectorInt> ; <NTCo:R:VectorInt>
                 :: Vector Int ~# Vector Int)
    of _ { Vector ipv ipv1 ipv2 ->
    letrec {
      $s$wfoldlM'_loop :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#
      $s$wfoldlM'_loop =
        \ (sc :: Int#) (sc1 :: Int#) ->
          case >=# sc1 ipv1 of _ {
            False ->
              case indexIntArray# ipv2 (+# ipv sc1) of wild { __DEFAULT ->
              let {
                x :: Int
                x = I# wild } in
              --
              -- Calls cmp and unboxes the Int result as I# y
              --
              case cmp @ a w w1 w2 w3 x x of _ { I# y ->
              $s$wfoldlM'_loop (+# sc y) (+# sc1 1)
              }
              };
            True -> sc
          }; } in
    $s$wfoldlM'_loop 0 0
}

-- helper function called by test - it calls $wa which calls boxed cmp
--
test1
  :: forall a.
     (Unbox a, Eq a) =>
     Vector a -> Vector a -> Vector Int -> Id Int
test1 =
  \ (@ a)
    (w :: Unbox a)
    (w1 :: Eq a)
    (w2 :: Vector a)
    (w3 :: Vector a)
    (w4 :: Vector Int) ->
    case $wa @ a w w1 w2 w3 w4 of ww { __DEFAULT ->
    (I# ww) `cast` (Sym <(NTCo:Id <Int>)> :: Int ~# Id Int)
    }
```

I will appreciate pointers on how to force unboxed version of `cmp` to be called from `test`. I tried strictifying different arguments, but that was like throwing the kitchen sink at it, which of course didn't work. I hope to use the lessons learnt here to solve the boxing/unboxing performance issue in the more complicated code.

Also, one more question - I have seen `cast` being used in the core, but haven't found any core references on Haskell/GHC wiki that explain what it is. It seems a type casting operation. I would appreciate explanation of what it is, and how to interpret it in the `test1` function above.

Comment: @leventov, good points about refactoring. About `INLINE`, I usually use it, but I left it as `INLINABLE` because in the more complicated code I was trying, it wasn't working. It seems though that applying your suggestions fix the issue. I will check more later - have to read the core again to make sure this is the case.

Comment: @leventov, your suggestions fixed the issue. You may want to answer this one (if you also know what `cast` means, it would be nice if you could explain it as well). I forgot that my go implementation violated worker-wrapper pattern because it took all arguments from main function though it didn't need them. `INLINE` assertion also seems necessary in order to unbox. Lesson learnt.

Comment: I haven't investigated GHC `Core` syntax too. When I analyze core, I use `-dsuppress-all` and don't pay attention to residual `cast`s.

Comment: Casting is for coercing between different types that have the same representation, such as newtypes.  It's described in the TLDI 2007 paper at  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/

Comment: Here is a brief description of the cast that you observed in the GHC output.  The coercion `Sym <(NTCo:Id <Int>)> :: Int ~# Id Int` is passed to `cast` to enable the cast.  Its type says that it permits a cast from `Int` to `Id Int`.

Comment: `test` needs to be `INLINABLE` so that the functions can be specialised at the call site.

Comment: @DanielFischer, good point. Thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I don't have `ghc`, so my advices would be verbal:

- Why do you avoid `{-# INLINE #-}` pragma? High performance in Haskell is significantly based on function inlining. Add `INLINE` pragma to the `go` function.
- Remove first two excessive parameters of `go` function. Read more about interoperation of inlining, specializing (unboxing) of parameters  here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-pragma
- Move `m` and `n` definitions one level up, along with `go`.

Comment: may I edit your answer to add the code that fixes the issue? I will like to add details before accepting it.